# How to add a context menu to an empty tableview's header row?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a `TableView`. If it has columns, I can add context menus to the columns, and the menu will appear when I right click on the column header.

How do I add a context menu to the blank bar that appears for an empty table? Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by accessing the internal structure of the TableView directly, I'm unaware of any official API to do this.

The [official TableView CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tableview) names a class of `column-header-background` which we can then access via the [Node#lookup()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) method.

An example

```
public class ContextMenuOnTableHeader extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TableView<String> table = new TableView<>();
        Scene scene = new Scene(table);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(200);
        primaryStage.setHeight(200);

        primaryStage.show();

        Node header = table.lookup(".column-header-background");
        header.setOnContextMenuRequested(event -> {
            ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
            menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Mr Horse"));
            menu.show(header, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
        });
    }

}
```